# Meaning of Orphaned Dollar Sign in Docker

Tags: docker, keystore

Hi I'm trying to analyze a `Dockerfile` but am having trouble analyzing it. Basically, there is a line where a Java keystore is being created. However, instead of a keystore name, a `$` character is used where the name of the keystore file should be.

The relevant command is as follows:

```
RUN keytool -noprompt -import -alias my-ca -file my-ca.pem \
    -storepass $TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD -storetype JKS -keystore $
```

When I run this command locally, a keystore file with a filename `$` is produced. By that I mean that the generated keystore file name is a literal dollar sign. However, this doesn't make a lot of sense and I wonder if something else is happening inside the Docker container and that the dollar sign is some kind of placeholder for some other name.

The full contents of the `Dockerfile` is as follows:

```
FROM openjdk:11.0.6-jdk-slim

LABEL maintainer="My Team"
LABEL version="2.1"

# build args
ARG KAFKA_VERSION="2.4.0"
ARG SCALA_VERSION="2.12"

# env vars
ENV KAFKA_BROKERS="myserver.mycompany.net:9093"
ENV KAFKA_CONSUMER_GROUP=""
ENV KAFKA_OPTS="-Xmx512m"
ENV KAFKA_TIMEOUT_MS="20000"
ENV KAFKA_SHIFT_BY="1"
ENV KAFKA_SOURCE_TOPIC=""
ENV KAFKA_SOURCE_TOPIC_PARTITION=""
ENV KAFKA_SINK_TOPIC=""
ENV KAFKA_USERNAME=""
ENV KAFKA_PASSWORD=""
ENV KAFKA_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION="/usr/local/kafka/truststore.jks"
ENV TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD="password"

ADD https://downloads.apache.org/kafka/$KAFKA_VERSION/kafka_$SCALA_VERSION-$KAFKA_VERSION.tgz .
RUN tar -xzf kafka_$SCALA_VERSION-$KAFKA_VERSION.tgz && \
    mv kafka_$SCALA_VERSION-$KAFKA_VERSION /usr/local/kafka

ADD https://myserver.mycompany.com/docs/ca-certificates/my-ca.pem .
RUN keytool -noprompt -import -alias my-ca -file my-ca.pem \
    -storepass $TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD -storetype JKS -keystore $


COPY KafkaCopyMessage.java /usr/local/kafka/
COPY print_input_arguments.sh \
     prepare_kafka_consumer_props.sh \
     check_consumer_group_state.sh \
     shift_offset_and_copy_messages.sh \
     /usr/local/scripts/

WORKDIR /usr/local/scripts/
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

ENTRYPOINT chmod +x /usr/local/scripts/*.sh && \
  ./print_input_arguments.sh && \
  ./prepare_kafka_consumer_props.sh && \
  ./check_consumer_group_state.sh && \
  ./shift_offset_and_copy_messages.sh
```

Thus, within the context of the above Docker `RUN` command, what does this dollar sign mean? I tried excessive Googling, but to no avail.

Comment: Is there anything more in the dockerfile? As you suspect, the dollar might be part of some variable, like $TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD used in the same command

Comment: @shree.pat18 Good comment. I have added the full `Dockerfile` as per your request.

Comment: Thanks. Looking at the value assigned, I suspect that the author may have intended to use $KAFKA_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION as the value for keystore.

Comment: @shree.pat18 Good call out. Thanks a bunch. So am I correct in surmising that this line is actually creating a keystore with a filename that is a literal dollar sign? The same behavior that exists on my laptop?

Comment: Hmm, I expect you would need to escape the dollar sign within the dockerfile for it to work.

Comment: Ya when I ran it locally, there was no need to escape the dollar sign. Because the dollar sign was orphaned, my Mac interpreted the dollar sign as a literal dollar sign instead of the start of a variable name. Perhaps that's what's happening in this command as well when it's run by Docker.

Comment: But I suspect that you're right about the intent of the original author.